# Scrapy finishes crawl prematurely

Tags: python, scrapy

I've had a crawler running successfully for months but the last few weeks it's been finishing prematurely after only a few crawled pages out of tens of thousands of pages that should be crawled.

It's a `SitemapSpider` with the following `sitemap_rules`.

```
class FooSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "foo"
    sitemap_urls = ["http://www.foo.se/sitemap.xml"]
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/bostad/', 'parse_house')
    ]
```

All the url's that I want to crawl looks like this:

```
http://www.foo.se/bostad/address-1-259413
http://www.foo.se/bostad/address-2-275754
```

There are aprox 50,000+ pages like this that should be crawled, but instead the spider stops crawling after sometimes 0 crawled pages and sometimes just a handful of pages crawled, without error. It just says:

```
2015-06-25 19:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-06-25 19:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 106313,
 'downloader/request_count': 310,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 310,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2809108,
 'downloader/response_count': 310,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 309,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'file_count': 21,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 21,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 17, 37, 38, 154000),
 'item_scraped_count': 4,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1717,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'log_count/WARNING': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 310,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 289,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 289,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 289,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 289,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 17, 35, 51, 868000)}
2015-06-25 19:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I've also tried changing the `USER_AGENT`, `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and the server/ip that I run the spider from, to make sure that it's not the target that is stopping my requests.

Any ideas? Any suggestions of what I should debug? It's difficult since I get no errors.

Here is a complete log of a crawl with 0 errors: 
http://pastebin.com/psQX6BCk

Comment: Quick check, which version of scrapy you are running on? (there was an upgrade to 1.0 several days ago)

Comment: You seem to have one error: `'log_count/ERROR': 1`, can you paste the logs?

Comment: I have pasted the logs in a pastebin and edited my question. @Lawrence the error in my example was from a duplicate image file name. It was not effecting the crawl and it is not in the pasted log. It got 0 errors.